# THE PRESENT PERFECT and THE PAST CONTINUOUS - do they work?

Tags: tense

I heard this combination of tenses in a video.

**I have heard it many times when I was reporting on him.**

I think it's not exactly correct. But the speaker was native.

Another example:

**Have you ever been rejected while/when you were confessing your feelings?**

What do you think of this tense combination?

Comment: Both perfectly natural.

Comment: But it's not in line with rules. One is in the past, the other one is in the present.

Comment: What would be the difference "Have you ever been rejected while/when you have been confessing your feelings?

Comment: I see no present tense. As has often been pointed out on these forums, native speakers avoid using perfect tenses when the meaning is clear without. **When I have been reporting on him** is logical but unidiomatic.

Comment: Kate, "Have you ever been rejected " - is the present perfect

Comment: The 'present perfect' refers to the past, not the present.

Comment: Technically, the present perfect is a present tense. Yes, it refers to the past. But if it referred to the past the same way as the past simple there wouldn't be the present perfect. The present perfect continuous refers to both: to the present and to the past. It's not so simple.

Comment: _The question is about things that have happened in the past!_ There is no inconsistency  with the second half of the sentence - see my comment above.

Comment: So, in this case this is correct. "I have been studying German, when I was living in Germany." But it's WRONG.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141870/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-user1425).